# $K(S,2)=\{b \in K^{\times}/{K^{\times}}^2\mid v(b)≡0 \bmod2, \forall v \notin S\}$ and Selmer group

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, number-fields

This question is essentially related to the theory of elliptic curves (Selmer group), but this question itself is just a field theoretic one.

To calculate the Selmer group of given elliptic curve, we often encounter the following set $K(S,2)$.

> Let $K$ be a number field and let $Ω_K$ be all places of $K$. Let
> $Ω_f$ be all finite places of $K$ and $Ω_∞ $ be infinite places. Let
> $S=Ω_∞\cup \{b\in Ω_f \mid v(2)\neq 0 , v(17)\neq 0 \}$.
>
> Define $K(S,2)=\{b \in K^{\times}/{K^{\times}}^2\mid v(b)≡0 \bmod2,
> > \forall v \notin S\}$.

Then, in the case of $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $K(S,2)$ can be identified with $\{±1,±2,±17,±34\}$.

But I wonder what happens when $K$ is an imaginary quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

For example, in the case of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19}$), what is the order of $K(S,2)$?
Unit group of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19}$) is $\{±1\}$, so I first thought $K(S,2)=\{±1,±2,±17,±34\}$, but $K(S,2)$ may be bigger.
If you prefer, another imaginary quadratic field you like (For example, $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$) is also appreciated.

My try: As the same as the case of $\Bbb{Q}$, every $b \in K(S,2)$ is the product of units and
**prime elements $a_i$ such that $v_2(a_i)\neq 0$ or $v_{17}(a_i)\neq 0$**.
I want to determine all such $b \in K^{\times}$.

Related one(computational approach thanks to Chris Wuthrich's comment);
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695456/sage-math-code-of-selmer-generatorss-m-proof-true

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a Selmer group for $\mu[2]/K$; it is in a short exact sequence between the $S$-units modulo squares and the $2$-torsion part of the $S$-class group. You need to determine the units and the class group to find the generators of $K(S,2)$. K.selmer_generators(S, m) does this in sage.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell me the sage code in the case of my question ? I tried to input while watching https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/polynomial_quotient_ring.html, but having trouble how to input the information about $S$ in my question.

Comment: This may be a separated computational question, so I reopened a new question in mathstackexchange. I would be grateful if you would answer in that mathstack page, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695456/sage-math-code-of-selmer-generatorss-m-proof-true.

Comment: K.<t> = NumberField(x^2+19); S = K.primes_above(2) + K.primes_above(17); K.selmer_generators(S,2). But I really think you should work it out by hand in this case. It is easy and it will teach you a lot more.

Comment: [thematic tutorials like this](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/explicit_methods_in_number_theory/nf_galois_groups.html) is where you can learn how to use the basic function in sage and then ask specific questions [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/)

Comment: @Chris Wuthrich, thank you very much. I really appreciate you. I'll try to calculate it by my hand with the help of your code.